# Finding meta "description" and "keyword" form a String using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, meta-tags

I have a string var webpageHtml containing HTML content of entire page.

How to find meta "description" and "keyword" from it, using javascript?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Use the DOM API, use `createDocumentFragment` to create a new document fragment, put the HTML in it, and then use `querySelector` to select the meta description and keyword from it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it is done in jQuery:

```
var metaDesc = webpageHtml.find('meta[name="description"]');

var metaKeys = webpageHtml.find('meta[name="keyword"]');
```

Comment: There was no mention of jQuery. But in any case, this is incorrect. `webpageHtml` *isn't* a jQuery object.